# Move files from private google bucket to a google drive

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

well we basically store some files on buckets in Google cloud, now I started to work on a feature to schedule tasks and move files, so what we want is the user to provide an api key/secret of google drive in order to move these files periodically to its drive, I noticed that we could do it using google account integration but in our solution that is not something we want because the integration would be tied to that specific user.

another thing that we are looking for is to avoid downloading the files because they could be a lot or they can be very big, therefore we would love to just provide like the bucket file/folder url and copy them to google drive.

note: the user owner of the bucket and the owner of the drive are different

I also did my research and found a lot of questions here on SO but they are very old, I guess if there is a new way.

Comment: You must read from Cloud Storage and write to Google Drive. I am not aware of a service to do that for you. Google Drive and Cloud Storage require an OAuth 2.0 Access Token to authorize requests. Your users must share their Drive folder with your service account email address. I recommend writing some test code so that you understand how each service works.

Answer (score 0):

Base on [this article](https://www.thecloudverse.com/gcs-to-gdrive/#deploy-cloud-function), you may create a google cloud function base on python libraries of both [GCS](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/main/samples/snippets/storage_copy_file.py) and and [Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads#multipart).

Also, you may try google collaboratory as describe on [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681533/add-files-from-google-cloud-storage-to-drive)